# Python flask project - while git init I got asked about X-code

Tags: xcode, git

starting my journey with Python (flask, sqlalchemy).
I tried to push some of initial code to my git repository, but when:

```
git init
```

I get:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer), missing xcrun at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcrun
```

This project has nothing to do with Xcode.
Sometime ago I was trying to learn a little bit Swift, using Xcode, but now I do not even have this IDE installed on my mac.

How to fix it and simply initialize my git repo for this simple Python project?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, actually I **had** xcode installed on my mac. Removed, problem fixed.